# Vertical Healthbar

Tags: java, slick2d

Right now I'm working on a game and I'm implementing a health bar. I got stuck making the right formula. This is my code of the Hud you see in the image:

```
public class CharacterHUD {

    private Image image;
    private Player player;

    private float xHealth, yHealth;
    private float healthBarWidth, healthBarHeight;
    private double healthBarY = 0;
    private double multiplier;

    public CharacterHUD(float xHealth, float yHealth, Image image, Player player) {
        this.image = image;
        this.player = player;
        this.xHealth = xHealth; // X Offset from the frame, 20 in this case.
        this.yHealth = yHealth; // Y Offset from the frame, 17 in this case.
        healthBarWidth = 38;
        healthBarHeight = 173;
    }

    public void update(int delta) {
        healthBarY = (yHealth / 100 * player.getHealth());
        multiplier = (yHealth / healthBarY);
        Log.log("Percentage: " + multiplier);
        Log.log("yHealth: " + yHealth + "+ Health: " + healthBarY);
        Log.log("Actual yHealth: " + (healthBarHeight * multiplier));

    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {
        // The coordinates are going from top-left(x,y) to bottomright(width,height). Also, the yHealth is the offset from the frame. 
        Resources.healthBar.draw(xHealth, (float) (healthBarHeight / multiplier) + yHealth, healthBarWidth, (float) (healthBarHeight / multiplier));
        image.draw(0, 0);
    }

}
```

On 50 health it looks like this:

[image: So]

On 75 health it looks like this:

[image: So2]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `multiplier` supposed to do?

Comment: @Dennisch Isn't that just restating the OP's problem?

Comment: It would kind of help if you had separate variables for the bounding box of the health bar "container" and the health bar itself. It's not perfectly clear when you're drawing what, you should explain what the parameters to `draw()` mean. Also, if `Player.getHealth()` a `double`? If not the fact you're using integral division might contribute.

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be `healthBarHeight * multiplier`? It seems that `multiplier` will be a number between `0` and `1`, so you should, in fact, multiply the maximum height to get the height up to which you should be filling in the bar.

Comment: Ok, maybe I answered the question a little bit too literally :)

Comment: Actually what would be ideal if you could provide a test case that doesn't really depend on a bunch of other code. I.e. just fill in a rectangle with a solid color using the most basic Slick2D calls possible, without using resources or depending on the implementation of the `player` object or whatever. If for no other reason than reducing the cognitive load that filling in the blanks requires.

Comment: added some comments to the declarations. Also please note that the y should get lower as the health gets lower.

Answer (score 2):

Would it be

```
Resources.healthBar.draw(xHealth, (float) (healthBarHeight / multiplier) - yHealth, healthBarWidth, (float) (healthBarHeight / multiplier));
```

instead of `+ yHealth`?

Note: I am not familiar with the method you are using but it seems like it is using window coordinates (from the top left) which would mean the y-coordinate to start from should decrease as health increases.

Comment: The coordinates are going from top-left(x,y) to bottomright(width,height). Also, the yHealth is the offset from the frame.

Comment: @TimondeGroot This sort of information belongs in the question. I.e. in comments next to the parameters for `draw()`

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation for the height of the bar is backwards.  I don't know what order the parameters in that Resource.HealthBar are in or what they allow, but here's some pseudo code for what you want.

```
topLeft = (healthBarLeft, healthBarTop + (1 - healthPercent) * healthBarHeight)
bottomRight = (healthBarLeft + healthBarWidth, healthBarTop + healthBarHeight)
```

The (1 - healthPercent) means that when you have 10% health left, the bar will start 90% of the way down.

Edit: If it doesn't support topLeft / bottomRight and instead expects a width / height, use:

```
dimensions = (healthBarWidth, healthPercent * healthBarHeight)
```

Comment: This is the way for horizontal healthbar. But, this is a vertical one and the X coordinate should get lower when the health gets lower.

Comment: @TimondeGroot Um. Are you sure it's the **X** (i.e. the "left"/"width") coordinate that should go **lower**?

Comment: Ohhh I keep messing up x and y :p. I meant Y.